# Why array = array1 equal to array1 = array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm try to check if the passed array is sorted or not:

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] list){
    boolean isSorted = true;
    int[] arr = list;
    selectionSort(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != list[i]){
            isSorted = false;
            break;
        }


        }
     return isSorted;
    }
```

I passed the array `list` and make  array `arr` equal to list, what happened is the array `list` became equal to array `arr` after sorting.

What is java rules for that?  and what should i do to separate `arr` from `list`?

Comment: `int[] arr = list;` doesn't copy the array. You'd need to use `int[] arr = list.clone();` or `int[] arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, 0, arr.length);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int[] arr = list;` doesn't copy the array, it just declares a variable which points to the same array instance.

You'd need to use `int[] arr = list.clone();` or `int[] arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, 0, arr.length);`.

---

But note that you don't need to sort an array to check if it is sorted: just check each element to see if the following element is smaller.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; ++i) {
  if (arr[i + 1] < arr[i]) return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: simply yes, but why `list` resorted between I do that with `arr` only?

Comment: @CODE1010101010101 I have no idea how to parse your comment.